# Formula for dynamic image src in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, dynamic-image-generation

I have taken a OLE object selecting paint brush option. after that going in  picture tab clicked x-2 button to write formula.
Wrote 2 formulas
**1. "F:/BrWeb/BrWeb/QRImages/DSR2022263.jpg"

2. "~/QRImages/DSR2022263.jpg"**
but image is not shown in report.
**Questions**
whats the mistake I have done?
How to write correct formula so that my image appears?
Can I user server path instead of static path in formula?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change "F:/BrWeb/BrWeb/QRImages/DSR2022263.jpg"

to "F:\BrWeb\BrWeb\QRImages\DSR2022263.jpg"

Comment: yeah. I solved using same code. thanks for your reply.

Comment: can you tell me how to write the root URL address without whole address? just like something "~/.....". is there any way?